# How to use ADL in Constraints?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, argument-dependent-lookup

As an example, I want to use a constraint to ensure that the function `isinf` is implemented for a template parameter `T`. If `T` is one of `float`, `double`, `long double` or an integral type, this can be done in the following way:

```
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
concept Test = requires (T a) {
    std::isinf(a);
};
```

However, I also want to use this constraint for custom, non-standard data types for which I implement my own `isinf` function. This function is not contained in the `std` namespace, so I tried the following instead:

```
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
concept Test = requires (T a) {
    using std::isinf;
    isinf(a);
};
```

This does not work since every statement in the requires clause should be a valid requirement and `using std::isinf` is not a "requirement" at all.

I see two workarounds to this problem:

- Move the `using std::isinf;` clause to the global namespace. But this introduces `isinf` to the global namespace, which I'd like to avoid.
- Encapsulate the `using std::isinf;` clause with the concept definition in a namespace named `ABC`, then add `using ABC::Test;` directly after the namespace. This seems a little bit weird.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this sort of thing works in Ranges is by creating a Customization Point Object. This closely mirrors your second option (we stick a using-declaration in a custom namespace) except we also provide an mechanism for users to call the correct `isinf` without having to write a bunch of the same kind of boilerplate themselves.

A customization point object for `isinf` would look something like this:

```cpp
namespace N {
    // make our own namespace
    namespace impl {
        // ... where we can bring in std::isinf
        using std::isinf;

        struct isinf_t {
            // our type is constrained on unqualified isinf working
            // in a context where std::isinf can be found
            template <typename T>
                requires requires (T t) {
                    { isinf(t) } -> std::same_as<bool>;
                }
            constexpr bool operator()(T t) const {
                // ... and just invokes that (we know it's valid and bool at this point)
                return isinf(t);
            }
        };
    }

    // we provide an object such that `isinf(x)` incorporates ADL itself
    inline constexpr auto isinf = impl::isinf_t{};
}
```

And now that we have an object, a concept follows directly:

```cpp
template <typename T> 
concept Test = requires (T t) {
    N::isinf(t);
}
```

This is precisely how the [`range`](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.range) concept is specified.

Comment: This looks like my answer but with more steps. Assuming the user enables `isinf` ADL for his type, what is the benefit of using this method over my suggestion?

Comment: @Mestkon It gives you an object `N::isinf` that you can use to do the dispatch. And since it's an object, you can do things like pass it into algorithms.... so like `ranges::any_of(r, N::isinf)` works.

Comment: Hmm, that's correct. It's a slight benefit of not having to write `[](auto t) { return adl_isinf(t); }` at the cost of more complexity. Depends on what the user needs more. https://godbolt.org/z/KEbjGG

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is way more lines of code than I would have preferred, but at least it keeps things simple in the rest of the code. As a side note, the semicolon in the compound requirement on line 12 should be moved to the end of the line according to gcc and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I'm not that comfortable with c++20 concepts so I cannot guarantee that the syntax is correct.

```
namespace impl {

using std::isinf;
template<class T>
auto adl_isinf(T t) -> decltype(isinf(t));
// { return isinf(t); } // implementation not necessary depending on whether
                        // requires is an unevaluated context
}

template <typename T>
concept Test = requires (T a) {
    impl::adl_isinf(a);
};
```

Comment: This looks basically like the OP's second workaround to me.

Comment: Yes, it is. The difference of defining the concept in the main namespace instead of importing it with a `using` statement might be enough to remove some of the "weirdness" OP is talking about though.

Comment: Yes, I prefer your solution over my second workaround. I tested your code and the syntax is correct, but you wrote `using std::inf` instead of `using std::isinf` in line 3. I can't edit your answer since the change would be less than 6 characters.